# Problems got from deploy from ACR to ACS DC/OS

Tags: c#, azure, acs, dcos

I’m now stumbling with manually deployment from Azure Container Registry to Azure Container Service DC/OS.

**Problem 1**: I followed the how-to articles from Microsoft.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-dcos-acr, the stdout in marathon application says the below error, (I pushed a asp.net core application)

```
System.ArgumentException: Http request Host is not specified
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.HttpRequestExtensions.GetUri(HttpRequest request)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.DiagnosticListeners.HostingDiagnosticListener.EndRequest(HttpContext httpContext, Int64 timestamp)
   at Proxy_Method_From_<>f__AnonymousType0`2_To_Void OnEndRequest(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext, Int64)(Object , Object , IProxyFactory )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.DiagnosticSourceAdapter.Write(String diagnosticName, Object parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DiagnosticAdapter.DiagnosticSourceAdapter.System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 value)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication.DisposeContext(Context context, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Who do you know I can approach for getting error clear out?

**Problem 2:**
When I somehow pushed another image per VSTS build with agent "Hosted VS2017", and created another marathon app, now the error is new,

```
Failed to launch container: Failed to run 'docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock pull *****.azurecr.io/travel.*****.*****.web:latest': exited with status 1; stderr='unknown blob '
```

Where's error come from?

**To answer Problem 2**: it's caused by container built per "Hosted VS2017" is windows container, to clear this error, it's has to be built per "Hosted Linux Preview"

Comment: What's the result if you run docker command in your local machine?

Comment: @starain-MSFT it works fine in my local machine, I doubt it's caused by .UseApplicationInsights(), I removed it and now the stdout log is quiet, previously the above err logs were flushing into stdout.